# North Node cross longitude?

Tags: the-moon

It appears that that swetest can tell the exact longitude as long as you give it the date and time

```
./swetest -pt -b17.11.2023 -ut22:43
date (dmy) 17.11.2023 greg.   22:43:00 UT        version 2.10.03
UT:  2460266.446527778     delta t: 69.109781 sec
TT:  2460266.447327659
Epsilon (t/m)     23°26'18.3245   23°26'10.2223
Nutation          -0° 0' 7.8330    0° 0' 8.1021
true Node         24°29'59.7465    0° 0' 0.0000    0.002502442   -0° 3'35.2933
```

Now my question is can one get the time and date for the nodes if it gives the longitude  lets say `24.5` same as the one in the swetest example .. can we calculate using swisseph, kind a like how solcross does  or mooncross ?  I only need a little hint on how to do it .. thank u <3

Comment: The ``` has to go on a line by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think swisseph has that capability, but skyfield.searchlib.find_discrete() is made for this sort of thing.
You would need to pass it a function which returns an integer indicating whether the node longitude at a given time is east or west of the value you're searching for.
[The documentation](https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/searches.html) and an [answer here](/a/54642) have relevant examples.

Comment: thank you Mike, i really appreciate it <3

Comment: hey Mike G, can you give me another hint with this please ... i can't even sleep as i keep going over this thing :(  https://pastebin.com/NBUMFrtH

Comment: 1. observe from Earth instead of the Sun;
2. let function return ((observed_longitude - longitude) // 180).astype(int) % 2;
3. step_days = ~1/4 of the expected period;
4. filter longitude_times by in_state == 0

Comment: https://pastebin.com/dcUDALrB

Comment: That code looks at the longitude of the Moon itself and should find 12 or 13 crossings per year. Now try looking at its [orbital elements](https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/elements.html).

Comment: https://pastebin.com/z5S4HjCQ .... Not getting it, however I did played with the documentation that you posted first. I like that <3 however been a noob can be frustrating as hell  :)